# Есть код, который проигрывает звук при наведении на кнопку, все перепробованные методы не дают результата, звук играет только на 1 из 25

Tags: javascript, запрос

Проект некоммерческий, делаем для себя движок для "своей игры", код из интернета.

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/0.8.0/Tone.min.js'></script>

<script>
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('choise')[0];


function setupSynth() {
  window.synth = new Tone.Synth({
    oscillator: {
      type: 'sine',
      modulationFrequency: 0.5
    },
    envelope: {
      attack: 0,
      decay: 0.2,
      sustain: 0,
      release: 0.5,
    }
  }).toMaster();
}

function boopMe() {
  if (!window.synth) {
    setupSynth();
  }
  
  window.synth.triggerAttackRelease(600, '9n');
}

button.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  boopMe();
});
button.addEventListener('mouseover', boopMe);
</script>
```

У всех кнопок (игровое поле) один класс `.choise`, работает только одна. Пробовал разное, в том числе и `document.querySelector`, знаю что там как-то надо что-то зациклить, и что без этого они оба обращаются к первому в списке, но не могу разобраться как это прописать. Подскажите, пожалуйста.